# Get current folder name by a DOS command?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

Is it possible to get the current folder name (not current directory path)  by using a DOS command?  If so, how?

The closest I got was this but it doesn't do it:

```
for /f "delims=\" %%a in ("%CD%") do set CURR=%%a
echo.DIR: %CURR%
```

note: the above attempt was me attempting to tokenize the string and get the last token set as the CURR variable.

Comment: If you have any sort of GNU toolset installed, you should be able to go `cd | sed "s/.*\\//"` (That pipes the output of cd (cwd) into a regular expression search and replace, replacing everything before the final \ with nothing at all)

Comment: i need to avoid GNU tools so that the batch file will work anywhere for anyone.   My question is for "pure DOS" anyways.

Comment: Alright. A quick google showed a SO result for implementing regex search and replace in VBScript (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127318/is-there-any-sed-like-utility-for-cmd-exe) which could use the same syntax and create the same result - I believe VBScript has been built in since windows 98, so should be quite anywhere for everyone! (You could also very easily rejigger it to work on *nix OS', too)

Comment: FYI, neither `for /f` nor TomWij's `%~n*` are supported in MS-DOS. (Windows' `cmd.exe` is _not DOS,_ it's a native Windows program.)

Comment: [Are the Command Prompt and MS-DOS the same thing?](http://superuser.com/q/451432/241386), [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Shortest way I have found:

```
for %I in (.) do echo %~nxI
```

or within a .bat script:

```
for %%I in (.) do echo %%~nxI
```

or in .bat with Get value in variable.

```
for %%I in (.) do set CurrDirName=%%~nxI
echo %CurrDirName%
```

Explanation: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntfor.php

nx means file name and extension only

Comment: I like the link and the suggestion but when i put that in a batch file I get an immediate closing of the shell with no output.  there must be a syntax error in there somewhere?

Comment: The example will work on the command line interactively. To use it in a batch file you need to replace all occurrences of `%` with `%%`.

Comment: Also, the example does not correctly handle folder names containing a period (`.`), such as my %USERPROFILE% folder.

Comment: Note that if you output this to a file you have to be careful not to add an extra space.

Example: for %* in (.) do @echo %~n*> TmpFile

Comment: Yes, works if you replace '%' with '%%'.  Nice answer.  Would have been the accepted answer if that was noted earlier.

Comment: %~nd is not sufficient if the directory contains dot characters! To be safe it hast to be %~nxd !!

Comment: I think it needs to be %~nx. N for path, X for extension this then works with paths that have a .

Comment: How to set this variable with `for` not in batch file?

Comment: What do you mean with "not in batch file"?

Comment: Could you explain how exactly this works? Namely what `%*` and `%~nx*` are doing to get the directory name. I can't find any explanation for them on RvdW's site, that page seems like it contains more or less the same information than `for /?`.

Comment: Whatever this god-awful evil sorcery is, I'm glad it works. I'm familiar with most of the expansion-syntax, but I've never seen `*` used with it before o.o

Comment: most excelent trick... forcing the ./%CD to be treated as a SCRIPT/:PROC parameter

Answer (score 37):

If you want to know the current location of the batch file (and if your Windows isn't a very ancient release), type `for /?` in a 'DOS box' window. Scroll down. Read.

You'll find out, that you can now read (from *within* the batch file) these variables:

```
%0      - as the name how this batchfile was called
%~d0    - as the drive letter where this batchfile is located ('\\' in case of share)
%~p0    - as path (without the drive letter) where this batchfile is located
%~n0    - as filename (without suffix) of this batchfile
%~x0    - as filename's suffix (without filename) of this batchfile
%~a0    - as this batchfile's file attributes
%~t0    - as this batchfile's date+time
%~z0    - as this batchfile's filesize
%~dpnx0 - as this batchfile's fully qualified path+filename
[... and then some more ...]
```

This works for many cases. Assume, the batchfile is called `mytest.bat`. You may call it in different ways:

1. `..\..\to\mytest.bat`   ............................... *(relative path)*
2. `d:\path\to\mytest.bat` ...........................  *(full path)*
3. `\\fileserver\sharename\mytest.bat` ... *(path on remote share)*

...and you'll always get the right value in your variables.

Comment: wow, interestingly enough your right.  the command "echo %~dp0" solves my problem also and its more elegant.

Comment: Is this actually the current directory, or the path of the batch file?

Comment: @erict: path of batch file.

Answer (score 18):

I personally liked Toms answer, until it struggled with dots in dir names. [This](http://forums.devshed.com/windows-help-34/finding-last-token-in-batch-file-412970.html) gave me a hint:

```
for /f "delims=\" %%a in ("%cd%") do echo topmost dir: %%~nxa
```

Answer (score 10):

Tom's answer is good, but if you have a directory name with a period in it (i.e. wxwidgets-2.9.4) you'll only get the full name. So this would output wxwidgets-2.9 instead because the .4 has been treated as an extension (Yes, even though it's a directory name!).

To get the full output name you have to add on the extension to the end:

```
FOR %I IN (.) DO Echo %~nI%~xI
```

and in batch file mode:

```
FOR %%I IN (.) DO Echo %%~nI%%~xI
```

Or of course, set a variable in the batch file instead:

```
FOR %%I IN (.) DO SET CurrentD=%%~nI%%~xI
```

Answer (score 6):

You can get the current dir into a variable. One-liner:

```
set a=%cd%
```

Check with

```
echo %a%
```

Comment: He wants the current directory name, not the whole path, and as a==cd, you may as well use %cd%.

Answer (score 5):

An other way is:

```
set "MyPath=%~dpnx0" & call set "MyPath=%%MyPath:\%~nx0=%%" 
echo MyPath=%MyPath%
```

it works with "." and spaces in pathname

What does it do?

1. put the whole filename (driveletter-path-filename-extension) into `MyPath` Var
2. remove filename and extension from `MyPath` var

It also works with UNC Paths. If you need the Backslash on the end of the Path. Remove the `\` after `MyPath` in the second set command, eg.

```
set "MyPath=%%MyPath:%~nx0=%%"
```

Comment: So how is this different from `%~dp0`

Answer (score 3):

just simple

```
for %%d in ("%CD%") do echo %%~nxd
```

or

```
set "sPath=."
for %%d in ("%sPath%") do set "sDirName=%%~nxd"
```

Be careful of the backslash of the end of path, it has not to be backslash of the end.

Answer (score 1):

My answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280969/windows-batch-loop-over-folder-string-and-parse-out-last-folder-name) does it in 3 simple lines:

```
@echo off
SET "CDIR=%~dp0"
:: for loop requires removing trailing backslash from %~dp0 output
SET "CDIR=%CDIR:~0,-1%"
FOR %%i IN ("%CDIR%") DO SET "PARENTFOLDERNAME=%%~nxi"
ECHO Parent folder: %PARENTFOLDERNAME%
ECHO Full path: %~dp0
pause>nul
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me from a batch file. It returns the current working directory name.

```
pushd %1 & for %%i in (.) do @echo %%~ni
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost all of the above code options will lead to an error if you call the bat file from the outside by other script or program. For example, this code: for %%I in (.) do set CurrDirName=%%~nxI, when called from Notepad++, will output Notepad++, but I don't need a parent Notepad++ folder name surely!
It is a bad way.
In addition, for the same reason, do not use %cd% and any other options. Use only the input parameters of this, maybe remotely located script. Otherwise, you will get the result for the calling, but not called script and what is written in its command line, but not what must be written in the command line of the called code.
Use this code for avoid errors:

```
    set path=%~p0
    set path=%path:~0,-1%
    For %%A in ("%path%") do (Set CurrDirName=%%~nxA)
```

Answer (score 0):

---

```bash
set "_cd=%cd:\=" & set "_cd=%"
```

---

It is possible to expand in a **[`set _with=auto-expanded variable`](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429)** command
using the variable that stores the current folder/path **`%cd%`** and get the name of the current folder at the same time saving that value in a variable without using **`for | for /f`** loop and/or additional **command** line:

---

```all-bat
echo %cd%
C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Temp

:: set _cd with auto expansion from value of %cd% ::
:: set _cd=C:\Users\ecker\AppData\Local\Temp      ::

set "_cd=%cd:\=" & set "_cd=%"
echo %_cd%
Temp
```

---

- To visualize how autoexpansion operates, use:

```bash
echo %cd:\=" & set "_cd=%
C:" & set "_cd=Windows" & set "_cd=System32
```

[image]

---

- Inspired by references:

---

- **[`Set /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**
- **[How-to: Windows Environment Variables](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)**
- **[How-to: Edit/Replace text within a Variable](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)**
- **[How-to: Extract part of a variable (substring)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)**
- **[Split string into substrings based on delimiter](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429)**