# Get current folder name instead of current path in windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get current folder name by a DOS command?](https://superuser.com/questions/160702/get-current-folder-name-by-a-dos-command)

In my batch file, I have,

```
SET currentFolder=%CD%
echo "%currentFolder%"
```

Prints the whole directory path.

```
C:\www\scritps\
```

I need to get `scripts` alone

Comment: Answer already [here](http://superuser.com/questions/160702/get-current-folder-name-by-a-dos-command).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There really isn't an easy way to do it.  This works in a .bat file:

```
for %%* in (.) do @echo %%~n*
```

Comment: that's fantastic (of course, * can be replaced with a letter), out of interest, howcome you used *  ?   btw, FWIW for any that don't know, # and ? work too. %%? and %%#

Comment: I didn't want to use something like "x" (or another letter) because I didn't want the original poster to get confused at the "~nx" part.  But you're right, you could substitute any letter there.  Coding in DOS .bat is so archaic that it's sometimes difficult to see what's going on.

Comment: This doesn't play well with directories that use `.` in their names. Any tips?

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck see answers for directions with spaces, periods, etc., in https://superuser.com/questions/160702/get-current-folder-name-by-a-dos-command