# How to check if the current batch file is in a specific folder?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, working-directory

Hi I'm fairly new to batch files, so sorry if this question seems stupid but I really need some help.

So I need my batch script to check if it is in a specified folder, say `%userprofile%\Desktop` for example. I don't want it to care about its own filename. I have absolutely no idea where to start. I know how to get the current path/filename etc but that's about all I know. How do I make the program compare its current path with the path that I want to see if it's in? Or is there another more efficient method?

What I want to achieve is like this:

```
if this file is in Desktop folder(
    echo It's here
)else(
    echo It's not here
)
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks everyone

Comment: Did you check 

    echo %cd%

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419868/what-is-the-current-directory-in-a-batch-file

Comment: @user648026 %cd% will not show the path of the batch file, but only the current directory. The current path is something like %~p0 but I forgot the exact syntax.

Comment: see link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419868/what-is-the-current-directory-in-a-batch-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current folder name by a DOS command?](https://superuser.com/questions/160702/get-current-folder-name-by-a-dos-command)

Comment: My main problem was with the comparing of the paths, but thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to apologize as the question you raised is more tricky than you probably expect.

#### Solution

This is how you can test that your batch file is located in a specific folder, in your case in Desktop folder:

```
@echo off

:: Normalize this batch script's path
set BATCH_PATH=%~dp0
set BATCH_PATH=%BATCH_PATH:~0,-1%

:: Test for equality
if "%BATCH_PATH%"=="%USERPROFILE%\Desktop" (
    echo This file is on Desktop.
) else (
    echo This file is not on Desktop.
)
```

#### Things to note

- alternative way to normalize path (and my favorite) is:

  ```
  pushd "%~dp0"
  set BATCH_PATH=%CD%
  popd
  ```

  - in any case, you probably want to remove any trailing `\`, which is one of the things the normalization does for you
- use `%~dp0` variable instead of `%cd%`, because the latter semantics is *the folder your scripts operates on* while the first is *the folder your script is located in* (which is what you asked for)

  - `%0` gives you your batch script location
  - by adding `dp` (i.e. `%dp0`) you ask for *disk* and *path* which omits the filename and extension (which is something like `example.bat` and it would be burden in next step - equality check)
  - by adding `~` you ask to remove any opening or closing `"` if necessary (i.e. the path contained space)
- paths are wrapped in `"` to prevent errors due to possible space in the path string

---

Not as simple as one would thought, right?

Comment: Indeed it's not, thanks for the answer and clarification on %dp / %cd%.I realized something while playing around though, it's that when I replace %USERPROFILE%\Desktop with C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp (common startup folder) it seems to execute the code no matter what. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You are welcome. The script works for me correctly if I test for the `StartUp` folder. I would need more details - especially the code, what it does and what you expect it to do.

Comment: Btw there are two startup folders now a) `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp` and b) `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Comment: I used the code from the answer below (I don't really see a difference other than that his answer didn't set the path as a variable). It works on all folders I've tested other than either startup folder.

Comment: My code:

`@echo off
IF %~dp0 == %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\ (
    ECHO It's here
) ELSE (
    ECHO It's not here
)
IF %~dp0 == %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\ (
    ECHO It's here
) ELSE (
    ECHO It's not here
)
IF %~dp0 == C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp\ (
    ECHO It's here
) ELSE (
    ECHO It's not here
)
pause`

Comment: It returns
`It's here
It's here
It's not here
It's here
It's not here`
when I put it on the Desktop

Comment: I see and I am getting the very same output as you. The reason for it is that the equality test in **last two if statements** are broken and both **if** and **else** block gets executed. The first *if* is fine. The reason for it is that the path to `Startup` folder contains space and you/Art didn't put the path in double quotes as I did.

Comment: right, I forgot to add that. I added the quotes and indeed the program works now! Thank you for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Minimal working example using `%cd%`:

```
IF %cd%==%userprofile%\Desktop (
    ECHO It's here
) ELSE (
    ECHO It's not here
)
```

Using intermediate variable:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('cd') do SET CURRENT_DIR=%%a
IF %CURRENT_DIR%==%userprofile%\Desktop (
    ECHO It's here
) ELSE (
    ECHO It's not here
)
```

Since you said you have no idea where to start, here is a good reading material:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting

Comment: -1, this does not answer the question.

Comment: This did solve my problem (for now), and thanks for the link! I'll be sure to read up on it. But some sources say there's a difference between %cd% and %~dp0, with the former presenting a different path sometimes? I'm somewhat confused

Comment: This answer was written at times that it was not clear if Mantis is asking for `%cd%` or `%~dp0` solution. The question title asked for script's filepath, but the question body cited "current directory" twice and it was tagged with "working-directory". Hence the confusion.